# Randomly sample with if-else condition in R

Tags: r, random

Given a data frame in the form:

```
group          val
A              10
A              1
B              9
C              6
...
```

I'd like to sample the `val` in each `group` randomly, with a new data frame as result. The problem is that the number of `val` in each `group` is different, so I can't use `sample()` directly. Now I'd like to determine the sample size in a `if-else` condition: if the number of `val` is higher than, let's say, 3, then three `val`s are sampled. Otherwise all the `val` are taken as samples. How can I do that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @akrun you said I did it? Indeed I don't know what are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'group', we get the `sample` of 'val'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(val=sample(val)), by = group]
```

If we need to add a condition such that `if` the nrow is greater than 3, `sample` 3 values or `else` all the values.

```
setDT(df)[, if(.N >3 ) sample(val, 3, replace=FALSE) else sample(val), by = group]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I sample the `val` with the size determined by if-else condition? Thanks.

Comment: @user5779223  I didn't see your comment.  Updated the post